# How do I override initializer in Realm Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, realm

I have a model that I need to create a composite key for.  I want to use KVO to update the composite key when the one of the two primary key columns is changed.  I can't seem to figure out which init method to override to register for KVO.  I've overridden

```
 - (id) init
 - (id) initWithValue:(id)value
 + (instancetype) createOrUpdateInRealm:(RLMRealm *)realm withValue:(id)value
```

and added log statements.  None of them are showing up in the console.  I'm using Realm+JSON to create these objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you're querying for an already persisted Realm object, it uses a private initializer method that isn't publicly available.

```
@interface RLMObject ()

// unmanaged initializer
- (instancetype)initWithValue:(id)value schema:(RLMSchema *)schema NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;

// live accessor initializer
- (instancetype)initWithRealm:(__unsafe_unretained RLMRealm *const)realm
                       schema:(RLMObjectSchema *)schema NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;

@end
```

You could try overriding these methods and attaching the observer there, but I'd recommend trying to avoid that if possible.

One thing we usually recommend is you implement a separate, custom accessor method that updates the properties you otherwise would have changed, and then implement the reactive change logic in that logic as well.

Beyond that, Realm also [recently added the ability to add notification blocks to individual objects](https://realm.io/news/realm-objc-swift-2.4/) (as opposed to just collections), so I'd definitely recommend using that over KVO if you need it as well.

Comment: We're still building the api so I ended up adding a "compositeKey" field to the DTO.  It's not really an answer to this question since I'm not doing anything in Realm to handle this.  I'll leave the question up hoping your answer helps someone.